# How can I make an item with NBT data have a coloured name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command and I'm wondering how to add a coloured name to it (light green, specifically)

`/give @p minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Common Chicken Head\"}"},Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:feather_falling",lvl:1}],SkullOwner:"MHF_Chicken",AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:0.1f,Operation:0,UUIDMost:21470,UUIDLeast:179416}]} 1`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You already have most of it, you just need to add a `"color":"green"` to the JSON component for Name that you've already got:

```
Name:"{\"color\":\"green\",\"text\":\"Common Chicken Head\"}"
```

You might also like to remove the italic font that is given to named items automatically by using `"italic":"false"`

```
Name:"{\"color\":\"green\",\"text\":\"Common Chicken Head\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"
```

Edit: Based on the fact it's specifically a head, you should probably also limit the health boost to when it's on your head. This is done using `Slot:"head"`

```
{Slot:"head",AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:0.1f,Operation:0,UUIDMost:21470,UUIDLeast:179416}
```

So the full command is:

```
/give @p minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"color\":\"green\",\"text\":\"Common Chicken Head\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"},Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:feather_falling",lvl:1}],SkullOwner:"MHF_Chicken",AttributeModifiers:[{Slot:"head",AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:0.1f,Operation:0,UUIDMost:21470,UUIDLeast:179416}]} 1
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is very helpful :D